# How to get endpoints from other project using the default in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a class library project called `Application` with `Features`, this `Features` will have endpoints like this

```
[Route("vendor/get")]
public class GetVendorController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public GetVendorController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IList<GetVendorResponse>> GetVendor()
    {
        return await _mediator.Send(new GetVendorQuery());
    }
}
```

I also have a web project, so what I'm looking for is how do I get all endpoints from `Application.Features` into my web project.

I saw this github project https://github.com/isaacOjeda/MinimalApiArchitecture with similar pattern that I used. But it's using 3rd party library `Carter`

```
public class GetCategories : ICarterModule
{
    public void AddRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapGet("api/categories", (IMediator mediator) =>
        {
            return mediator.Send(new GetCategoriesQuery());
        })
        .WithName(nameof(GetCategories))
        .WithTags(nameof(Category));
    }
....
```

And then in `Program.cs` inside the web project:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.AddSerilog();

builder.Services.AddCustomCors();
builder.Services.AddPersistence(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.AddSwagger();
builder.Services.AddCarter();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Application));
builder.Services.AddMediator();
builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining(typeof(Application));

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors(AppConstants.CorsPolicy);
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.MapSwagger();
app.MapCarter();
app.Run();
```

Can I achieve the same thing without `Carter` or Nancy-esque library using the default ASP.NET Core library?

Answer (score 0):

> get all endpoints from Application.Features into my web project.

In a class library project, in  MyFeature folder,I have a controller : GetVendorController,and there is a Index action.

In my web project,I try to use IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider in HomeController as below , to get all endpoints from the class library project into my web project.

Web HomeController.cs:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider;

        public HomeController(IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider provider)
        {
            this.provider = provider;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var urls = this.provider.ActionDescriptors.Items
                .Select(descriptor => '/' + string.Join('/', descriptor.RouteValues.Values
                                                                                .Where(v => v != null)
                                                                                .Select(c => c.ToLower())
                                                                                .Reverse()))
                .Distinct()
                .ToList();

            return Ok(urls);
        }
}
```

result:

[image]